# Doxygen : How to use @see with operator Type

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm reworking my whole documentation for one of my library and I encounter an issue :

I've got a class with a method `operator bool ()`. But, when I use `@see Class::operator bool`, Doxygen don't generate a link to this function.

How can I format the `@see` field for resolving my issue ?
Thanks.

**Edit 1** : @IInspectable solves this in the comment, I forgot to put the `()` at the end. But now, I've got this function : `Class::operator tinyxml2::XMLNode*()` but Doxygen fails to resolve the function.

Comment: Perhaps try without a space between `operator` and `bool`, might look weird but I seem to recall that no spaces are allowed when using `\see`.

Comment: The operator is called `operator bool()` (note the trailing parentheses). Also make sure to add the `const` specifier, if present in source (it should be).

Comment: Already tried but this is the same result. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I would really like to know why one calls an operator `bool`

Comment: @IInspectable : Worked, but I've got another converting function : `operator tinyxml2::XMLNode*()` and this don't work (added the trailing parentheses).

Comment: @user4759923 Knowing if an instance is in a valid state.

Comment: Doxygen needs the cv-qualifier. In case `operator XMLNode*()` is `const`, you have to supply it in documentation as well. Apart from that, it could be, that the namespace/class `tinyxml2` isn't known to doxygen.

Comment: I know, but the function isn't `const`.

Comment: You should rather use an `isValid()` method instead of a cast to `bool`.

Comment: @user4759923 For better or worse, `operator bool()` is a common idiom in C++ for determining if an object is in a valid state. It appears frequently in the standard library (e.g. std::ostream, std::optional, std::shared_ptr, etc).